# How to remove unidentified strange border

Tags: html, css

In the following link there are strange black patterns at the top of the page that only show up on mobile devices, I checked on 2 different android devices that had the same case, but on my desktop computer it does not show up even when using different viewports.

The link: http://dshift.totalh.net/blog/solving-the-mossad-challenge/

A photo of the strange phenomenon:
[image]

There are weird black patterns on the top as you can see. How do I go about removing them? I have yet to identify the cause of the issue as well.

EDIT: I changed the picture with a higher res version, though the border had receded a bit, it's still there unfortunately, and making the image any larger will start to affect load performance. I'll update if i find another solution.

Comment: Could they be from the image? seems that the quality of the image could be the problem, try a `background-color` to find out if it is indeed the image causing it?

Comment: seems like your img zoom too much.

Comment: It appears to be because of the image as you mentioned, If one of you want to answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You can also change background-attachment from "fixed" to "scroll" on the body tag and it will remove the border.

Comment: Though you might be right @trav, i need it to be fixed, this is a blog post template and some posts might be very long and I can't have an image stretched to 10 times it's original size.

Comment: That's true.  Wasn't sure if you were dead set on that image alone.  Also you could use a linear-gradient for the background to achieve a similar look.

Comment: Yeah but it won't look as good, initially that's what I did, to make it look good I also added filters and because of the use of blur the performance took a big hit, and without any blur the gradient doesn't look as good. I'll try to find a different solution, thanks @trav.

Comment: No worries, best of luck with it all!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's, as i've told in the comments, something with the resolution of the image. You're able to check if it is the `background-image` causing the problem by changing the `background` to e.g. the following:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```